# Can I get the default value set by setdefault

Tags: python

If I set a default value on a dict, is it possible to get the default value back after its been overwritten?

Like this:

```
dd = {}
dd.setdefault('beverage':'A nice cup of tea')
...
dd['beverage'] = 'Yellow urine'
...
if dd['beverage'] not in list_of_valid_beverages:
    # If the beverage has been contaminated revert to default.
    # Something like any of the following?
    dd['beverage'] = dd.getdefault('beverage')
    dd['beverage'].clear()
    del dd['beverage']
...
print dd['beverage']
```

My guess is that this is not possible with an ordinary dict. Ones the statement

> dd['beverage'] = 'Yellow urine'

is executed the tea is forever lost. But it would be a nice feature :-)

Anyone with deeper knowledge about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. All `setdefault` does is the following logic:

```
if key not in the_dict:
    the_dict[key] = value
return the_dict[key]
```

It does not treat the "default" value specially, and doesn't store it anywhere other than the location that you're overwriting.

If you want a set of persistent defaults, you're best off just keeping a separate `dict` of the default values.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can subclass `defaultdict` and override the `__missing__` function, so that you can get a new class that remembers when `__missing__` is called and saves the newly constructed default value.